# Alerta Resharper Access to modified closure

Tags: c#, warnings, resharper

`Implicitly captured closures` ou `Access to modified closure`

É um tipo de alerta que o `Resharper` mostra no código abaixo, gostaria de entender melhor este tipo de alerta e que tipo de problema pode acarretar no código em que ele é mostrado.

[image: closure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja este código para entender melhor:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<Action>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) lista.Add(() => WriteLine(i));
        for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) Metodo(lista[c]);
        var lista2 = new List<Action>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var tmp = i;
            lista2.Add(() => WriteLine(tmp));
        }
        for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) Metodo(lista2[c]);
    }
    public static void Metodo(Action func) => func();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RZzHHb). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJULUX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Capture.cs).

Antes de ver executando, o que espera que aconteça? Que imprima os números de 0 à 1? É isso que está alertando. Você provavelmente espera algo que não vai acontecer. Este código irá imprimir 10 vezes o número 10 que é o último valor de `i`, a variável capturada na *lambda*. Pode ser que é o que deseja, mas é improvável.

A solução é criar uma variável intermediária só para suportar a *lambda* e a captura ocorrer corretamente. Assim:

```
var lista2 = new List<Action>();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var tmp = i;
    lista2.Add(() => WriteLine(tmp));
}
for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    Metodo(lista2[c]);
}
```

As mensagens de erro são:

> Closures implicitamente capturadas

Esse problema está relacionado ao fato de que uma referência foi capturada pela função anônima e irá sobreviver mais do que deveria e é bom você saber bem o que está fazendo, isso pode provocar um vazamento de memória

> Acesso a uma closure modificada

Usou uma variável capturada que não tem o valor provavelmente pretendido

Comment: Poderia explicar o que significa os termos `Implicitly captured closures` ou `Acess to modified closure`?

Comment: Só a tradução?.

Comment: A tradução e uma explicação eu não consegui entender o que exatamente este termo quer dizer, acho que os tradutores online estão traduzindo 'ao pé da letra' =/